# trying to add ajax request html to page source

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm working on a project using ajax and PHP, my problem is when I add HTML markup with ajax it's not showing in page source and that preventing my from making another request to delete this markup and the only way that makes my delete it redirect to the same page.

this is my markup code:

```
<div class="card">

    <div class="card-content">
        <form>
            <div class="input-field">
              <textarea id="textarea1" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
              <label for="textarea1">Type something here</label>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="card-action">
        <button id="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" disabled>Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="cards--wrapper">
<?php  
    $query = "SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY id DESC";

    $retrieve_posts_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($retrieve_posts_query)){
        $content_id = $row['id'];
        $post_content = $row['posts'];
        $post_date = $row['date'];
        $post_date = strtotime($post_date);
        $post_date = date('j F, Y', $post_date);



?>
    <div class="card" data-id = "<?php echo $content_id; ?>">
    <a class="btn-large waves-effect waves-light red right delete">+</a>
        <div class="card-content">
            <?php echo $post_content; ?>
            <span> <?php echo $post_date; ?> </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

and this is my ajax code :

```
window.onload = function(){

    $('#textarea1').keyup(function(){
        var messageInput = $(this).val();
        if( messageInput !== '' ){
            $('#submit').attr('disabled', false);
        }else {
            $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
        }
    });

    $('#submit').on('click', function(){
        retrieveData();
        return false;
    });

    function retrieveData(){
        var messageInput = $('#textarea1').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'server.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                message : messageInput
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('#cards--wrapper').prepend(data);
                $('#textarea1').val('');
                $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
                window.location.href = 'index.php';
            }
        });
    }

    $('.delete').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var that = $(this);
        var cardID = that.parent().data('id');
        var el = that.parent();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'delete.php?delete='+ cardID +'',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(){
                el.remove();
            }
        });

    });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `server.php` is returning something? Use Developer Tools to see what it's returning.

Comment: server.php for inserting and selecting data from database

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. I didn't ask what it's for, I asked you to check that it's actually returning something. Go into Developer Tools, go to Network, then make the AJAX call. You can then view the response.

Comment: it inserting data to database

Comment: If it's inserting data into the database, why are you trying to insert the result into the HTML? What kind of result does it return?